# angular js select box item missing after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I trying to set drop-down box display the default item. First, item in drop-down box able to display correctly and I can select the item in order to save into database. Everything working fine, the problem is after I refresh the page, the default item always is empty, it should display the item that I save.

```
HTML
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="sst_type" ng-options="type for type in 
 sst_types" ng-change="changeSstType(sst_type)"></select>
```

JS

```
.controller('sstCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, Module, settings, 
toastr, actionBar, $uibModal) {
  // scope properties
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.sst_types = ['Sotong', 'Bento'];
    $scope.sst_all = [];
    // scope functions
    $scope.getSst = function () {
      Module.getSst().then(function (res) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        if (res.sst_all) {
          angular.forEach(res.sst_all, function (v) {
            $scope.sst_all.push({
              id: v.id,
              name: v.name,
              value: v.value,
              percentage: (v.value * 100).toString(),
              type: v.value == 0 ? 'Sotong' : 'Bento'
            });
          });
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: well, in order this to open you need to get the DATA you save in the DB and set it to the modal you have on the select. ng-model="sst_type"
this way it will set the selected option(if the value is like in the sst_type)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the id of the saved item from server. You can do that in the Module.getSst() call. 
In foreach set $scope.sst_type to the matching one.

Good luck